# Rydberg Frequency

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, frequency, orbitals

Is the frequency of radiation emitted or absorbed = $R_\nu(\dfrac {1}{n_i^2}-\dfrac {1}{n_f^2})$ where $R_\nu$ is the Rydberg Frequency = $3.29 \times 10^{15}$ Hz?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct.  A frequency (or spectral energy) emitted in a transition from $n_1$ to $n_2$ therefore represents the photon energy emitted or absorbed when an electron makes a jump from orbital $1$ to orbital $2$.